# UnderscoreJs Mixins in RequireJs module

Tags: javascript, requirejs, underscore.js, mixins

Wrote this requireJs model for 2 underscore mixins that I need for my application.
I added it to   require.config and the file loads but when I try to use either of the 2 functions I declared they are undefined. I know I am doing something wrong but I don't know what.

```
define(['underscore.mixins'], function (module)
{
    require(['underscore'], function (_) {
        _.mixin({
            'toQueryString': function (parameters) {
                var queryString = _.reduce(
                  parameters,
                  function (components, value, key) {
                      components.push(key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value));
                      return components;
                  },
                  []
                ).join('&');
                if (queryString.length > 0) {
                    queryString = '?' + queryString;
                }
                return queryString;
```

**Update 1:**

I modified it but it still doesn't work for me.
I did this:
main.js:

```
require([
    '../common/requireConfig'
], function () {
    'use strict';

    requirejs.s.contexts._.config.paths.chai = 'thirdParty/chai';
    requirejs.s.contexts._.config.paths.mocha = 'thirdParty/mocha';
    requirejs.s.contexts._.config.paths.sinon = 'thirdParty/sinon';

    requirejs.s.contexts._.config.shim.mocha = {
        exports: 'window.mocha'
    };

    requirejs.s.contexts._.config.shim.sinon = {
        exports: 'window.sinon'
    };

    //  Then, load all of the plugins needed by test:
    require(['test/plugins']);
});
```

requireconfig.js

```
define(function () {
    'use strict';

    require.config({
        baseUrl: 'js/',
        enforceDefine: true,

        paths: { ... }
});


require(["underscore", "thirdParty/underscore.mixins"], function (_) {
    _.toQueryString({});
});
```

but when I call the function:
in a model file

```
 requestUrl += _.toQueryString(_.extend({
                    key: YouTubeAPIKey
                }, ajaxDataOptions));\
```

it is still undefined

**Update 2**

Got it to work by doing this:
underscore.mixins.js:

```
define(['underscore'], function (_) {
    _.mixin({
        'toQueryString': function (parameters) {
            var queryString = _.reduce(
                parameters,
                function (components, value, key) {
                    components.push(key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value));
                    return components;
                },
                []
            ).join('&');
            if (queryString.length > 0) {
                queryString = '?' + queryString;
            }
            return queryString;
        },

        'fromQueryString': function (queryString) {
            return _.reduce(
                queryString.replace('?', '').split('&'),
                function (parameters, parameter) {
                    if (parameter.length > 0) {
                        _.extend(parameters, _.object([_.map(parameter.split('='), decodeURIComponent)]));
                    }
                    return parameters;
                },
                {}
            );
        }
    });

    return _;
});
```

And at the top of the file where I actually use those functions:

```
define([
    'background/collection/songs',
    'background/key/youTubeAPI',
    'background/model/song',
    'common/enum/songType',
    'common/enum/youTubeServiceType',
    'common/utility',
    'thirdParty/underscore.mixins'
], function (Songs, YouTubeAPIKey, Song, SongType, YouTubeServiceType, Utility,_) {
```

Comment: I would recommend rolling back this question to what it was initially. You had a clear question then. Everything you've added afterwards have just made things murky. You've already accumulated a downvote and a vote-to-close. Even if people do not continue downvoting, it is **extremely** unlikely that anyone else will look at your question in its *current* state, say "yes, I'm having this problem too" and upvote your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `require` inside your `define` seems completely unnecessary and would indeed complicate how other modules would use this module because once the module is loaded, there is no guarantee that the mixins *are actually registered*. This is because `require` is asynchronous and the `define` *will* return before the code passed to `require` runs.

I'm able to add a mixin to Underscore like this. As soon as a module obtains `foo`, it is guaranteed that the mixin is registered with Underscore.

`foo.js`:

```
define(["underscore"], function (_) {

_.mixin({
    foo: function () { 
        console.log("foo invoked"); 
    }
});

});
```

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xhtml; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/require.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      require.config({
        baseUrl: "js"
      });
      require(["underscore", "foo"], function (_) {
        _.foo();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but unfortunately it still doesn't work for me. See Update 1.

Comment: Got it to work by adding return _; in foo.js. See Update 2. If this could be done better some other way please let me know.